# I have created a Maven Project in Spring Tool Suite, it is not showing the proper project structure like "src/main/java", JRE, Maven,etc

Tags: maven

[This is the Screen Shot, if I'am creating source folder inside the project as "src/main/java" then it's showing error- It's not a java project, but I have created this as a Maven Project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6hGU.png) I have created a Maven Project with name "testProject", the proper structure of the project is not populated, only "src" folder,target and "pom.xml" is visible. And also it is showing "No actions available" under "Build Path" submenu.

Comment: post a hierarchy of project structure if possible.

Comment: Sometimes the Eclipse Maven plugin gets stuck, especially in older versions. Have you tried right-clicking the project, selecting Maven > Update > OK? If that doesn't work, try deleting the project from the workspace (without deleting the project on disk) and reimport the project as a Maven project.

Comment: This deleting the project from the workspace (without deleting the project on disk) worked for me, Thankyou so much.